# Android: draw shape inside another shape

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to draw an oval shape inside another oval shape, but the second one should be cut off when it reaches the border of the first one.

This is the desired result:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: see `android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode`, more on that: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to draw an oval shape inside another oval shape, but the second one should be cut off when it reaches the border of the first one.

As  pskink said, you could use [PorterDuffXfermode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) to implement this feature, here is an simple :

```
public class DrawView : View
{
    public DrawView(Context context):base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        RectF oval2 = new RectF(60, 100, 300, 200);
        canvas.DrawOval(oval2, paint);

        //PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop means Discards the source pixels that do not cover destination pixels. Draws remaining source pixels over destination pixels
        paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop));

        paint.Color = Color.Black;
        RectF oval3 = new RectF(110, 150, 350, 250);
        canvas.DrawOval(oval3, paint);

        this.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
        paint.SetXfermode(null);
    }
}
```

Effect :

[image]